# In Google Analytics I need a Path that shows me only people who converted and what their path was all time

Tags: google-analytics

In path exploration section of GA4 can I see data of only the people who have converted from my ads

I tried using creating a segment of people that converted and I also tried using a medium = cpc filter but it gives an error "No data for this combination of segments, values, filters, and date range. Try editing the variables or settings or remove them."